# Sequence satisfying inequality $u_{n+1} \le (1+A) u_n +B$ for $n=0,\cdots,N-1$ , $A,B \ge 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm having difficulty solving this problem.

Let $(u_n)$ be a real sequence and $A,B$ real nonnegative constants and $N \in \mathbb{N}^*$ satisfying

$$(\forall n \in \{0,1,\cdots,N-1 \}) \quad : \quad u_{n+1} \le (1+A)u_n + B$$

It is asked to prove, by induction, that for all $n\in \{ 0,1,\cdots,N\} $

$$u_n \le e^{nA}u_0+\dfrac{B}{A}(e^{nA}-1)$$

My try :

I noticed that the provided condition implies :

$$v_{n+1} \le (1+A)v_n $$ (*)

where $v_n:=u_n + \dfrac{B}{A}$

it would have been enough if $(v_n)$ was positive since multiplying side by side inequalities (*) from $n=0$ to $n=m-1$ would give

$$v_m \le (1+A)^mv_0$$

and we would conclude using $1+A \le e^A$ .

But here nothing seems to force $(v_n)$ to be positive , taking for instance :

$u_0 = -2$
$u_1=1$
$B=5$
$A=1$

gives no apparent contradiction.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is because $1+A$ is positive.

Comment: @xpaul I can't see how it's relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by $\,(1+A)^{n+1} \gt 0\,$:

$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{(1+A)^{n+1}} \le \frac{u_n}{(1+A)^n} + \frac{B}{(1+A)^{n+1}}
$$

Adding from $\,0\,$ to $\,n\,$ and telescoping:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{u_{n}}{(1+A)^{n}} &\le u_0 + \frac{B}{1+A}\left(1 + \frac{1}{1+A}+ \ldots \frac{1}{(1+A)^{n-1}}\right)
\\ &= u_0 + \frac{B}{1+A} \cdot \frac{1 - \frac{1}{(1+A)^n}}{1 - \frac{1}{1+A}}
\\ &= u_0 + \frac{B}{A}\left(1 - \frac{1}{(1+A)^n}\right)
\\ \implies\qquad u_n &\le (1+A)^n u_0 + \frac{B}{A} \big((1+A)^n - 1\big)
\\  &\le e^{nA} u_0 + \frac{B}{A} \big(e^{nA} - 1\big)
\end{align}
$$

The last step uses the inequality $\,1+A \le e^A \implies (1+A)^n \le e^{nA}\,$, and assumes $\,u_0 \ge 0\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ The proposition does not hold true in general without the assumption that $\,u_0 \ge 0\,$. For example $\,A=1, B = 0, u_0 = -1, u_1 = -2\,$ satisfies the premise $\,u_1 \le 2 u_0 = -2\,$ but does not satisfy the conclusion $\,u_1 \le e u_0 = -e\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the recurrence

$$
u_{n+1}+s_n^2=(1+A)u_n+B
$$

we have the solution

$$
u_n = (1+A)^{n-1}c_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+A\right)^{n-k-1}\left(B-s_k^2\right)
$$

then

$$
u_n\le (1+A)^{n-1}c_0+B\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+A\right)^{n-k-1}
$$

or

$$
u_n\le (A+1)^{n-1}c_0+\frac BA\left((A+1)^n-1\right)
$$

NOTE

Here $c_0 = (A+1)u_0$ and the recurrence was solved as

$$
\cases{
u_n^h=(1+A)u_{n-1}^h = 0\\
u_{n}^p+s_{n-1}^2=(1+A)u_{n-1}^p+B\\
u_n = u_n^h+u_n^p
}
$$

giving $u_n^h = (1+A)^nc_0$ and then putting $u_n^p = (1+A)^nc_n^0$ and substituting into the complete recurrence we got

$$
(1+A)^nc_n^0+s_{n-1}^2-(1+A)(1+A)^{n-1}c_{n-1}^0-B=0
$$

and thus

$$
c_n^0-c_{n-1}^0 = \frac{B-s_{n-1}^2}{(1+A)^n}
$$

obtaining

$$
c_n^0 = \sum_k \frac{B-s_{k-1}^2}{(1+A)^k}
$$

thus obtaining the particular solution as $u_n^p = u_n^hc_n^0$ etc.

The solution when $u_0$ is given, reads

$$
u_n=\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (A+1)^{n-k-1} \left(B-s_k^2\right)+u_0(A + 1)^n
$$

or

$$
u_n+\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (A+1)^{n-k-1} s_k^2=B\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (A+1)^{n-k-1}+u_0(A + 1)^n
$$

then always

$$
u_n\le B\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (A+1)^{n-k-1}+u_0(A + 1)^n = \frac{B (A+1)^n}{A}-\frac{B}{A}+u_0 (A+1)^n
$$

not depending on the value of $u_0$.

Comment: thanks but how have you solved the recursion from line 1 to 3. second question : do you mean by $c_0$ ,$u_0$

Comment: Please. Have a look at the attached note.

Comment: how about the case $u_0\le 0$ , a counterexample is given in @dxiv reply

Comment: Please. See the included additional explanation,